# Alamofire 3.0 Request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I try to make a request to my server getting info form my API. Therefore I do:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, requestURL).responseData { (response:NSHTTPURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            print(response)
        }
```

But I receive the error `Tuple pattern cannot match value of the non-tuple type 'Response'

Do I use the method in a wrong way?

The autocomplete shows me this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, requestURL).responseData(completionHandler: Response <NSData, NSError> -> void)
```

Comment: Reading the "Alamofire 3.0 Migration Guide" might help, in particular the section "Breaking API Changes" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the result from the `Result type` in [Alamofire 3](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#result-type). You could unwrap it with `switch-case` by pattern matching, show you a example:

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, requestURL).responseData { (response) -> Void in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
            // Here you go
            print(data)
        case .Failure(let error):
            // Error handle
            print(error)
        }
    }
```